# Building a specific array from a table of data

Tags: php, arrays

I have a table of data as such:

```
id   |   item   |   parent_id
1       item 1          0
2       item 2          0
3       item 3          2
4       item 4          3
5       item 5          1
...
```

The `id` is autoincrementing, and the `parent_id` reflects the `id` on the left. You may have come accross a database table design like this before.

The `parent_id` is not sequential as you can see.

I need to get this table data into an array in the format where all parents become a potential heading with their children underneath.

So I am looking at a structure like this:

```
Item 1
    Item 5
Item 2
    Item 3
        Item 4
etc
```

In `PHP` I need an array structure that can display the above. But I am having a serious brain fart!

Can anyone help me with the array structure?

Answer (score 0):

you may write somethin like this:

```
$a = Array(item1 => Array(item5), item2 => Array(item3 => Array(item4)))
```

or

```
$a = Array(item1 => parentid, item2 => parentid2 ....)
```

in the first example one item is the key for all ist children stored in the Array, in the other example all items are stored using an item key and an int value. this int value is the key for the parent item. which method you use depends on what you want to do with this Array. maybe both of my ideas are not good enough for your Needs. if thats the case, tell me what you need.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i will suggest you to read [this](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/), it's very useful for hierarchical structured data and there are available queries which will help you to get parents, children, etc ... and so and so.

Now to answer your question, try this :

```
$result = array();

while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $id = $data['id'];
    $parent = $data['parent_id'];
    $keys = array_keys($result);
    if(in_array($parent, $keys)) {
        $result[$parent] = array_merge($result[$parent], array($id => $data['item']));
    } else {
        $result = array_merge($result, array($id => $data['item']));
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting article - I'm not certain whether the db route is the best option for my problem as I can't be sure how deep the rabbit hole goes without further SQL.

Comment: yes, the deeper it is, the more the php code will be complicated ! if you use the nested set hierarchy, you will be able to just make a query that handle what you want without PHP stuff.

Comment: PS: my code isn't correct, i just tested it :p ! i m trying to correct it !